# How do i get the name of select tag if it is assigned using php? I want to store it in database

Tags: php

here is the code. I m using multiple select in the code having same values.
Please help me ..have to add different items in database so I am having multiple select tag at the same time different items can be added using different select options.

```
 <?php

$db_host='localhost';
$db_user='root';
$db_pass='';
$db_database='foodwrap1';
$con=mysqli_connect("$db_host", "$db_user", "$db_pass")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysqli_select_db($con,$db_database)or die("cannot select DB");
$id=$_SESSION['restid']; 
$sql="Select cat_name from category where rest_id=$id";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysql_error()."no data");

                 ?>
                      <td width="7" height="39"></td>
                      <td >Select Category</td> 
                      <?php $scat=implode("cat",$k);?>
                       <td colspan="3"><select name="<?php echo $cat?>">//name assigned to select 
                        <?php
             while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
             {


                $ca = $row[0];
            ?>
                          <option value="<?php echo $ca; ?>"><?php echo $ca;}?></option>
                        </select>




if(isset($_POST['additems']))
{
    for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
    {
    $icat=$_POST['']; // what to write here?how will i get the name.
    echo $icat;
    }
```

Comment: I assume you mean that you need to get the name in javascript? If the ID is dynamic and you do not wish to code the name as a javascript variable you could use `var oCol=document.querySelectorAll('select')` to get all the select menus and choose from there which one you need

Comment: <select name="<?php echo $cat?>"><select name="<?php echo $scat?>"> here i have assigned the name using php

Comment: <?php $scat=implode("cat",$k);?>  <select name="<?php echo $scat?>"> here i have assigned the name using php i want to get the value of select using $_POST[' '] but i don't know what to write in these quotes and assign it to a variable.I want to store these values in database.

Comment: Try simply using `$cat` in the $_POST - `$_POST[ $cat ]`

Comment: I tried that and its working..thanx..